# personalize mutt's subject with variable

Tags: linux, mutt

I've a script that send an email to user. I need to add a variable (name of new user) to subject. My example:

```
a="John";echo|mutt -s welcome$a -e 'my_hdr From:info@example.com <info@example.com>' test@example.com
```

Obviously this runs but the subject is: welcomeJohn. I need a space between welcome and John. A real space doesn't works, change from a="John" to a=" John" doesn'run... Either programmatically add a space to variable or put all subject to variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclosing subject with double quotes

```
a="John Foo";echo|mutt -s "welcome $a" -e 'my_hdr From:info@example.com <info@example.com>' test@example.com
```

It will send a mail with subject `welcome John Foo`. Change your command for required subject. You are free put spaces anywhere in subject or variable value now.

**Note:** It's standard practice to specify any input, variable for command line arguments to linux commands with proper quotes to mitigate white space issues.

`''` for literal string

`""` for variable substitutions

Comment: You may put as many space as you want either in subject of in variable value. See edit. It works for me atleast

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mutt -s "welcome $a"
```

instead of the current

```
mutt -s welcome$a
```

Comment: Yes, but mutt remove $a variable when send email